# Keras class_weight for generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

This is a continuation of a question:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22814/class-weighting-during-validation-in-keras

*class_weight* can be used in Keras *fit* function to tell the optimizer to weight the under represented class. According to the answer in stackexchange it is also considered during validation. For example, if my class ratio is 10 negatives for every 1 positive then an accuracy score of 0.8 is not so good (a fixed classifier on negatives will do better). I have two questions:

- How exactly class_weight is being considered during validation?
- How can I use class_weight in *fit_generator*? is it the same parameter as in *fit*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, it is considered the same way as during training.

Basically if you look at the function [weighted_masked_objective](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/621ec292c2609b82fd3f992b5a66f3d6611a4477/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L415), individual samples are multiplied with the weights, and the mean is returned back.(Note: Keras does not automatically set the class weights, you need to pass the weights at `model.fit()` or `model.fit_generator()`

Class weights can be computed by the inverse proportion to frequency. Using [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html)

`fit_generator` is identical to `fit`, except for the fact it takes a generator as input.

Comment: So for example if I have 9 False and 1 True and weights are {0:1, 1:9}, I get mean=(9x1 +1x9)/10=1.8. How exactly is it used for scoring?

Comment: Taking your example, with class weights of {0:1, 1:9}. Let my batch of training consist of labels[ 0,0,1,1,0], with losses [a,b,c,d,e], So the losses after the weights for that batch would be [a,b,9c, 9d, e]. There is no mean used!!!

Comment: Ok, I see why you asked about the mean, I had mentioned it in the answer, well that is because if you had class weights set as 0, it would compensate the loss accordingly, ex if weights are {0:1, 1:9, 2:0}, with labels [ 0,0,1,1,2], and losses [a,b,c,d,e] the final loss would be [1.25a, 1.25b,  11.5c, 11.5d, 0]

Comment: Is it fair to say that what they do de facto is multiply the confusion matrix by the weights? (so in my example every FP of class 1 is actually 9 FPs etc.)

Comment: Kind of yes, But it is the loss which is multiplied i.e for a simple loss, where `loss =  actual - predicted ` and with your example if two samples had predicted 0.3 for both class 0, 1 then the final loss would be `0.7` for class 0 and `-2.7` for class 1